# Google Sheets - Remove all HTML tags except <img> and <a> tags

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets document with data from a web scrape. I'd like to remove all HTML tags except links and images. I have managed to remove all HTML with the REGEXREPLACE function:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1;"</?\S+[^<>]*>";"")
```

...but I want to keep img and a-tags

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
=REGEXREPLACE(A1;"(?s)(<img[^>]*>|<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?</a>)|</?\w[^>]*>";"$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rubi2y/3).

*Details*

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier for the `.` to match any chars
- `(<img[^>]*>|<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?</a>)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern):

  - `<img[^>]*>` - any `img` tag
  - `|` - or
  - `<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?</a>` - any `a` tag with its open and close element and inner text
- `|` - or
- `</?\w[^>]*>` - `<`, an optional `/`, a word char, and then any zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>` char.